# Ionic Link Jumping Multiple Pages

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-view

I've just started using Ionic and recently built a small app with some basic pages and testing it on the **Ionic View** app.

There's some links in the sidebar:

**routes.js**

```
.state('app.dashboard', {
url: '/dashboard',
views: {
  'menuContent': {
    templateUrl: 'views/dashboard.html',
    controller: 'DashboardController'
  }
}
```

})

**menu.html**

```
<ion-item class="item item-icon-left" ng-href="#/app/dashboard" href="#">
```

When the link is tapped, the page shuffles around a couple of times then lands on the correct page.

The problem here is that it works on the Android perfectly, but it doesn't work properly on the iOS. The shuffle happens on the iOS.

Anyone experienced this problem before?

Answer (score 1):

Haven't figured it out yet but this might be causing the problems I've been having on iOS at:

http://blog.ionic.io/ios-9-potential-breaking-change/